# How to make a IE addon

Tags: internet-explorer

Can someone tell me where can I find documentation about how to make an IE8+ addon? I tried to look for it but it seems like I can't find documentation for it. I can only find documentation for old school addons (made for IE5 or so...)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home: its a nifty little way to do cross-platform browser plugins.